# Jquery: calling submit function from js code bypasses AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following dialog box and form

```
<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:300px;height:220px;padding:10px 20px"
        closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
    <div class="ftitle"></div>
    <form id="fm" method="post">
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Position Title:</label>
        <input name="position" class="easyui-validatebox" required="true">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="dlg-buttons">
    <a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-ok" onclick="savePosition()" id="submitButton">Save</a>
<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-cancel" onclick="javascript:$('#dlg').dialog('close')">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

I want the user to be able to either press enter, or click on the submit button to submit the form. The js that runs the submit is:

```
    function savePosition(){
        $('#fm').form('submit',{

            url: url,
            onSubmit: function(){
                return $(this).form('validate');
            },
            success: function(result){
                var result = eval('('+result+')');
                if (result.errorMsg){
                    $.messager.show({
                        title: 'Error',
                        msg: result.errorMsg
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#dlg').dialog('close');        // close the dialog
                    $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In order to allow the enter button to work, I decided to use the following code, but when the `savePosition();` function is called, it submits the form as if it were a standard form (takes me to the submit page). How can I make it so that the form is submitted as an AJAX form (like it is when the button is clicked)? I have also tried using `$('#submitButton').Click()` but this seems to submit the form, but the database isn't updated.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fm').submit(function( jqEvt ) {
        jqEvt.preventDefault();
        savePosition();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger a click-event should do the trick. Did you try it with a lower case 'c'?

```
$('#submitButton').click(); //Change from .Click to .click
```

Comment: I have tried with a lower case c, still takes me to the processing PHP page (the url parameter).